# How to pick the highest numbered version from every filename?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, sort

Input:

```
ganglia-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.7.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Output should be :

```
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I went through a method like taking prefixes and using `ls -v` command to get the versions ...

```
ganglia
ganglia-debuginfo
ganglia-dlevel
ganglia-web
.....
```

and used `ls -v prefix* | tail -n 1 ..`

I could get the perfect things, but only for the ganglia prefix. I'm not able to get the perfect thing.

Comment: Please don't vandalize the question and answers just  because you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Below may help to sort by major and minor version of the package , Just a thought it might help.

```
$ cat test | sed -e 's/-\([[:alpha:]]\)/+\1/g' |   sort -t - -n -k2 -r | sed -e 's/+\([[:alpha:]]\)/-\1/g'
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.7.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/([a-z])-([[:digit:]]+\.)+/\1 \2/' file |
  sort -k2Vr |
  awk '$1 in a{ next } { a[$1]; print $1 "-" $2 }'
ganglia-8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

- `sed`: replace the first `-` between the name and version suffix with a space character
- `sort`: on the second field by version in reverse order
- `awk`: skip the line if the name exists in the array, else save the name in the array and print name, `-` and version suffix

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -A max_version
for file (*.rpm(nN)) max_version[${file%-*-*.*.*.*}]=$file
print -rC1 -- $max_version
```

Where `*.rpm(nN)` is the list of `.rpm` files in the current directory sorted numerically. And we record the greatest version of package `x` (in `x-version-packageVersion.rel.arch.rpm`) in the `max_version` associative array.

That associative array ends up containing something like:

`$ typeset -p max_version
typeset -A max_version=( [ganglia]=ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm [ganglia-debuginfo]=ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm [ganglia-devel]=ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm [ganglia-gmetad]=ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm [ganglia-gmond]=ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm [ganglia-gmond-python]=ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm [ganglia-web]=ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm )`